# How do I find out the screen orientation, in portrait or landscape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frame, uiscreen

I can't believe this isn't possible. It's just one of those things that surely everyone must require.

So, this:

```
[UIScreen currentScreen] bounds];
```

returns a width of 320 on my iPhone, regardless of whether the phone is in portrait or landscape. So I made this helper method:

```
+(CGRect)screenFrame {

    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        return frame;
    }
    else {
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.height, frame.size.width);
        return newFrame;
    }

}
```

Which works great, except when the device is laying flat, apparently that makes it think it's in landscape, even if the screen doesn't change to landscape.

How can i tweak this to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best guidance (largely because of the 'laying flat' orientation) is to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`. This will then give you the correct value based on how the application has adjusted the main window's coordinate transform matrix.